# How to test the randomness of residual plot?

Tags: r, regression, diagnostic

Let's say in linear regression, I got a fit and I can plot residuals to see whether there is any systematic trend in such a plot. How to quantitatively determine whether the residues are really random? Is Durbin-Watson test used for this purpose? How to interpret such test if so?

Please provide an example, preferably in R.

Comment: **Related**: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14914/how-to-test-the-autocorrelation-of-the-residuals

Comment: See also the [Breusch-Pagan test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Pagan_test), where a reference to an $R$ implementation is also given.

Answer (score 2):

This also depends on the type of data you have. Do you have a **time series**? Then looking at a ACF/PACF plot of the residuals may be one way of determining if these are white noise:

```
require(tseries)
tsdiag(rnorm(100))
```

you may find this [PDF](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=pacf%20plot%20r&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http://www.statoek.wiso.uni-goettingen.de/veranstaltungen/zeitreihen/sommer03/ts_r_intro.pdf&ei=tdjtTsGULuWH4gT6wbSVCQ&usg=AFQjCNFk4Y762r-ENWM5PCTlnZxq5Dy_SA&cad=rja) helpful.

If you have **cross-section** data an inspection of the residual plots yields very valuable information in my opinion:

```
data(cars)
plot(lm(speed~dist, data=cars))
```

There exist tests (see comments) but I very often find graphs more useful.