# Avoiding spurious regression with cross-sectional data

Tags: time-series, meta-analysis, meta-regression, cross-section

I have been reading everything I can get my hands on about spurious regression but can't seem to definitively find out what is best in regressing cross-sectional data including non-stationary variables.

Example data:

```
Country  GDPyearofstudy         Popdensyearofstudy   Year of study Total(2013$)

UK      2462484285580                 2.63                   2011       0.5
Brazil  2143067871760                 0.23                   2010       1.5
USA     13095400000000                0.34                   2005       2.3
USA     14958300000000                0.37                   2010       1.5
```

Total observations: 49

I am conducting a meta-regression of values obtained from studies between 1990-2011.  My y variable is Total (2013$) and my x variables include GDP and Population density to help understand the valuation.  The year the study was undertaken is also included.  I was told using GDP and Population density could skew results through being non-stationary, so I attempted to calculate GDP growth as 100*log(GDP/lagGDP).  As I only have one observation for some countries however, this has mostly produced errors as there is no lag on a single observation.

My questions therefore are:

- Do I use GDP and Population Density for the year the original study was taken, or
   2013 which I have standardised Total(2013$) to?
- If this is cross-sectional, do I have to worry about GDP and Population Density
   being non-stationary?
- If they are non-stationary, will using the log of each be enough, or do I have to 
   use GDP growth which in my case mostly fails to produce a result?
- Can I simply adjust the standard errors?

I have run regressions using GDPyearofstudy; GDP2013; logGDPyearofstudy; logGDP2013; GDPgrowth and all fitted vs. residual plots look fine, Breusch-Pagan test is fine and all variables show a Pearson correlation of <0.6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess what: with a panel so short in its time dimension, non-stationarity of the whole process doesn't matter, because it is "unreachable". To illustrate:
Consider the following simulated random walk with drift:

$$x_t = 0.07 + x_{t-1} + u_t$$

with  $u_t \sim N(0,1)$ and independent from past and current regressors.
An $800$-period graph looks like

[image]

The two rectangles represent 20-period and the same 20 + 60 = 80-period windows respectively. How do they look like?

**The 20-period window**

[image]

**The 80-period window**
[image]

In all likelihood, you will not detect non-stationarity if all you have available is the 20-period sample, *because the 20-period window could very well be a realization from a stationary process*.  So non-stationarity of the *process* does not affect the available *realization* of the process (i.e. the data). Then it cannot create an artificial association between the variables.  The essence here is that non-stationarity needs a sample of some size, in order to potentially mislead us.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive and easy to understand answer!  In addition for anyone reading this, I found on another Cross Validated question a way of testing for autocorrelation of the residuals which I believe can be a symptom of spurious regression, and conducted the Breusch-Godfrey test.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14914/how-to-test-the-autocorrelation-of-the-residuals