# Fixed Effects vs Lagged DV vs. First Differences Regression

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model, lags

What are the differences between using unit fixed effects, unit fixed effects and time fixed effects, lagged DV, or first differences to analyze a time series with 4-5 time periods and 35-50 units per time period (depending on the subset)? In particular, how will they perform if both an $X$ covariate and the dependent variable $Y$ have consistent time trends, for example if both trend downwards over the time period under observation.

My current understanding is that if the dependent variable has a consistent time trend, for example if $Y_{it}= .9 Y_{it-1}+ \epsilon_{it}$ then using a lagged DV instead of a first difference model will bias estimates of the effect of $X$ on $Y$ towards zero, particularly if $Y$ and thus $Y_{t-1}$ are measured more precisely than $X$ and $X$ also has a time trend, because the time trend in $Y$ could be entirely a function of $X$, but with measurement error the regression will partition the explained variance across both $X$ and the lagged DV.

In terms of the fixed effects vs. first differences, I found this video series ([Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7WqK2o474Y) [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZnk-HpGizI), [Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLvdik53JMQ)) helpful for understanding which is better at handling different types of serial correlation. In particular, it says in part 2 that if the error (i.e. the residuals) $u_{i}$ are serially correlated then first differences will perform better, but that if $\Delta u_{i}$ are serially correlated then fixed effects is the way to go. How can I test for serial correlation? This [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14923) points to `dwtest` in `R`, but it's unclear to me how to test for serial correlation in fixed effects model using this function because it will not allow me to pass it a formula with fixed effects (I get the error `Error in chol2inv(qr.R(qr(X))) : element (51, 51) is zero, so the inverse cannot be computed`).

Finally, part 3 of the video series says that if an $X$ covariate is non-stationary and [unit root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_root) then the first difference model will preform better. My understanding is that an $X$ covariate that consistently trends downwards is unit root. Is that correct? Is there a more formal test I can do to determine whether or not an $X$ covariate is unit root?