# Which model for my data?

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, model-selection

I have this data:

```
Group Time  Size
A 1 0.56
A 2 0.97
A 3 1.33
A 4 1.75
B 1 0.12
B 2 0.24
B 3 0.31
B 4 0.47
B 5 0.51
B 6 0.69
B 7 0.73
B 8 0.85
C 1 0.16
C 2 0.23
C 3 0.38
C 4 0.49
C 5 0.53
C 6 0.66
C 7 0.78
C 8 0.81
```

Here is the respective plot:

[image]

Now I would like to test the three groups for differences in slope and intercept. I cannot use simple linear regression since these are time series and the data points are not independent of each other.

Here are the additional tests I performed on the linar model:

```
Data = read.table(textConnection(Input),header=TRUE)

model = lm(Size ~ Time + Group,data = Data)
```

Shapiro-Wilk test for normality:

```
shapiro.test(residuals(model))

p=0.001288 (not normally distributed)
```

Breusch-Pagan test for equal variances:

```
bptest(model)

p=0.016 (variances not equal)
```

Since residuals are not normally distributed and variances are not equal an ANOVA (for example) could not be performed. Furthermore, the residuals are auto-correlated according to the Durbin-Watson test:

```
dwtest(model)

p=0.001065 (data points auto-correlated)
```

Which model would be suitable for my problem (probably a multilevel linear model?) and which R packages I could use for the analysis?

**Another data set:**

```
Input = ("
Group   Time    Size
A   1   1.08152
A   2   1.10589
A   3   1.13292
B   1   1.04597
B   2   1.05763
B   3   1.07023
B   4   1.08612
B   5   1.10059
B   6   1.11589
B   7   1.13143
B   8   1.14741
B   9   1.16721
B   10  1.18288
C   1   1.04777
C   2   1.06145
C   3   1.07484
C   4   1.08908
C   5   1.10346
C   6   1.11866
C   7   1.13375
C   8   1.14931
C   9   1.16563
C   10  1.18294
")
dat = read.table(textConnection(Input),header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you can't use linear regression? Have you [tested](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14914/how-to-test-the-autocorrelation-of-the-residuals) if residuals are auto-correlated?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have constructed this model: model = lm(Size ~ Time + Group + Time:Group,data = Data) (according to https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/e_04.html) and performed a Durbin-Watson test with dwtest(model). The resulting p-value is 0.002353. Furthermore the data is not normally distributed: shapiro.test(residuals(model)) gives p=0.00795. I hope I did everything right.

Comment: Without see your acutal data frame, your model maybe assuming "Group" as a continuous variable and not a categorical value.  If you convert "Group" from numeric to a factor and then run the linear regression. The residual plot is more normal and thus a standard linear regression analysis is a safer assumption.  Also repeat the analysis without the group/time interaction term.

Comment: I converted "Group" to factor (A,B,C) and changed the model to model = lm(Size ~ Time + Group,data = Data). Breusch-Pagan test bptest(model) gives p=0.016 and Shapiro-Wilk test shapiro.test(residuals(model)) p=0.001288. If I am right, this means that the variances are not equal and the residuals are not normally distributed. Hence, an ANOVA (for example) could not be performed. Furthermore, the residuals are auto-correlated: the Durbin-Watson test dwtest(model) gives p=0.001065. This is my data frame: Data = read.table(textConnection(Input),header=TRUE).

Comment: The heteroscedasticity likely derives from the black points, which so obviously have a different slope there is no need to test them.  Consider, then, removing those points from the data and focusing on the remaining data.  Plotting the linear regression residuals against time would provide useful information about the nature and size of any remaining autocorrelation.

Comment: Removing the black points (Group A) would make everything easier, but they have to remain since they are part of the problem :). Group A has of course a different slope (and intersection with the y-axis) and I just need the proper tool to prove it. Without Group A the Durbin-Watson test gives p=0.888 (for model = lm(Size ~ Time + Group,data = Data)), the residuals become normally distributed (p=0.7863) and variances become equal (p=0.4452).

Comment: I wasn't suggesting ignoring the black points: my suggestion was to *analyze the data as two separate groups.*  At that point you will have the quantitative backup needed to state the obvious: namely, you will have independent estimates of slopes and the standard errors of estimate.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit about your goals? As whuber notes, that the black points are different is blindingly obvious. For most purposes, worrying about the small amount of autocorrelation would probably be unnecessary given the magnitude of the difference. Relatedly, I would keep the Group:Time interaction term in the model, because the slope of those black points is so clearly different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a relatively simple problem. The basic model to test your question about differences in slope is:

```
(m0 <- lm(Size ~ Time * Group, dat))
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         Time       GroupB       GroupC  Time:GroupB  Time:GroupC  
#      0.1700       0.3930      -0.1482      -0.1032      -0.2890      -0.2956
```

I have ignored the question about the intercepts. More on this at the end. Also, the basic model you ran does not permit testing of differences in slopes. If you perform the diagnostic tests you performed on the model `m0` here, they do not confirm misspecification.

However, it appears Group A is on a different scale, so it makes sense to run a heteroskedastic model. Additionally, as @whuber pointed out in the comments, it makes sense to model the autocorrelation. I use the simple autocorrelation of order 1:

```
library(nlme)
(m1 <- gls(Size ~ Time * Group, dat, correlation = corAR1(form = ~ Time | Group),
           weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | I(Group == "A"))))
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)        Time      GroupB      GroupC Time:GroupB Time:GroupC 
#   0.1768985   0.3900313  -0.1543012  -0.1146352  -0.2860587  -0.2912242 
# 
# Correlation Structure: AR(1)
#  Formula: ~Time | Group 
#  Parameter estimate(s):
#        Phi 
# -0.5295663 
# Variance function:
#  Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
#  Formula: ~1 | I(Group == "A") 
#  Parameter estimates:
#     TRUE    FALSE 
# 1.000000 2.152732
```

We find that the residual standard deviations of the groups that are not group A are about double the residual standard deviation for group A. And that there is negative autocorrelation - positive-negative residual switching pattern by time.

To address your primary research questions, we can go:

```
library(emmeans)
pairs(emtrends(m1, ~ Group, var = "Time"))
#  contrast    estimate          SE df t.ratio p.value
#  A - B    0.286058700 0.005098842 14  56.103  <.0001
#  A - C    0.291224187 0.005098842 14  57.116  <.0001
#  B - C    0.005165488 0.003857697 14   1.339  0.3979
# 
# P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

We find that there is not much statistical evidence to conclude that the slopes for Group B and C are different from each other. While there is the evidence to differentiate A from B, and A from C.

Since we have an interaction, it is difficult to consider differences in the intercept. Given the current analysis, the intercept relates to group differences at Time 0 which does not exist in the data, minimum Time is 1. The `emmeans` package provide an option to view differences between the groups at different values of time:

```
emmip(m1, Time ~ Group, cov.reduce = FALSE)
```

[image]

We find that as time increases, the group differences between A and B, and A and C increase. But B and C continue to be relatively similar. Be careful because there are no time point beyond time 4 for Group A, these are extrapolated values.

Given what we have learned, a parsimonous model would be:

```
m.pars <- gls(Size ~ Time * I(Group == "A"), dat,
              correlation = corAR1(form = ~ Time | Group),
              weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | I(Group == "A")))
```

Comment: +1.  It's nice to see how you handle the heteroscedasticity.  But, upon rereading the question, I notice it is also concerned about serial correlation over time within each group.  This possibility could invalidate most of the testing you have performed throughout the analysis.

Comment: @whuber I modified the response to account for the auto-correlation. It did not change much in this application - the patterns in these data are very strong.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I have indeed used the wrong model, now the tests for the shown data yield respective results. And the slope differences make sense, as you have shown. I have many more data sets with groups that have even less data (only three data pairs, see newly added data above). Here, Shapiro-Wilk test for normality yields p=0.0243 and the result from Durbin-Watson test is highly significant (p<=0.001).

Comment: With model m1 I see that the residual standard deviations of the groups that are not group A are almost the same as the residual standard deviation for group A. Regarding autocorrelation there is the same residual switching pattern by time. Pair-wise testing using pairs(...) throws an error: „Error in crossprod(x, y) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments“. I assume that this happens due to the small size of group A?

Comment: Pairwise may throw an error because your group variable is string not numeric. I am not sure. If you have many more data sets, can you create a new question to describe why you have many more data sets? Why do you intend to analyze each one separately?

Comment: The data is formatted as shown above ("Another data set:"). Group is Factor w/3 levels "A", "B", "C": 1 1 1 ..., Time is int and Size is num. The model m1 throws no errors, but the pair-wise testing does. Can you reproduce this error?

Comment: @ Heteroskedastic Jim: Could you please have a look at my last comment?

Answer (score 2):

Because your model uses longitudinal data, it is best to check for the Intraclass Correlation Coefficient (ICC) before assuming independence. However, this particualr model has a small sample size, so it is singular,

```
require(lme4)
my_lme=lmer(Size~Time+(Time|Group),data=my_data,REML=F)
isSingular(my_lme)
[1] TRUE
```

Let's try using a Bayesian model with a Wishart variance-covariance prior.

```
require(blme)
my_blmer=blmer(cov.prior='wishart',fixef.prior=NULL,resid.prior=NULL,
               formula=Size~Time+(Time|Group),data=my_data)
isSingular(my_blmer)
[1] FALSE
```

So it works now, but make sure you can justify the use of a Wishart prior. Let's check the ICC:

```
summary(my_blmer)
Cov prior  : Group ~ wishart(df = 4.5, scale = Inf, posterior.scale = cov, common.scale = TRUE)
Prior dev  : -1.4809

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['blmerMod']
Formula: Size ~ Time + (Time | Group)
   Data: my_data

REML criterion at convergence: -7.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.74016 -0.23951 -0.04383  0.26814  2.76185 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 Group    (Intercept) 0.54671  0.7394        
          Time        0.01784  0.1336   -0.98
 Residual             0.01331  0.1154        
Number of obs: 20, groups:  Group, 3

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  0.25213    0.43100   0.585
Time         0.06510    0.07882   0.826

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
Time -0.970
```

The ICC is quite large: $0.546/(0.546+0.017+0.133)=0.78$. Thus, you should be using a Hierarchical Linear Model (HLM). Also, because you have a small sample size, you should use a Bayesian HLM.

Comment: You don't show how OP should check which group time slopes are different from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Just code your groups as dummy variables, which I think may be what @whuber was suggesting. There is plenty of reference information available on the internet about dummy variables.

Like so:

```
time <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
size <- c(0.56, 0.97, 1.33, 1.75, 0.12, 0.24, 0.31, 0.47, 0.51, 0.69, 0.73, 0.85, 0.16, 0.23, 0.38, 0.49, 0.53, 0.66, 0.78, 0.81)
groupa <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
groupb <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
lm1 <- lm(size~groupa+groupb+time+groupa:time+groupb:time)

> summary(lm1)

Call:
lm(formula = size ~ groupa + groupb + time + groupa:time + groupb:time)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.035833 -0.021012 -0.003583  0.015768  0.043929 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.066786   0.022092   3.023  0.00912 ** 
groupa       0.103214   0.041156   2.508  0.02508 *  
groupb      -0.045000   0.031243  -1.440  0.17176    
time         0.097381   0.004375  22.259 2.51e-12 ***
groupa:time  0.295619   0.013413  22.040 2.87e-12 ***
groupb:time  0.006667   0.006187   1.078  0.29946    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.02835 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9963,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9949 
F-statistic: 746.2 on 5 and 14 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

And now your p-value for Shapiro-Wilks is 0.35, for Breusch-Pagan it is 0.45, and for Durbin-Watson it is 0.92.

For group A your equation is size = (0.066786+0.103214)+(0.097381+0.295619)*time.

Except I would probably run it again without 'groupb' and 'groupb:time', to get a single fitted line for groups B+C together.

Comment: With a longitudinal model, you need to check the ICC as in an HLM.

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt, thanks for the feedback, but too much jargon! What is 'ICC' and 'HLM'? Please use the unabbreviated terms so I have some chance to look up what you're talking about...

Comment: Intraclass Correlation Coefficient (ICC) and Hierarchical Linear Model (HLM)

Comment: Thanks. I've suggested adding the full terms in as an edit to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to fit a Bayesian MLM in R, look no further than the rethinking package. You also need to [install RStan](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started).

```
library(rethinking)
Input = ("
         Group   Time    Size
         A   1   1.08152
         A   2   1.10589
         A   3   1.13292
         B   1   1.04597
         B   2   1.05763
         B   3   1.07023
         B   4   1.08612
         B   5   1.10059
         B   6   1.11589
         B   7   1.13143
         B   8   1.14741
         B   9   1.16721
         B   10  1.18288
         C   1   1.04777
         C   2   1.06145
         C   3   1.07484
         C   4   1.08908
         C   5   1.10346
         C   6   1.11866
         C   7   1.13375
         C   8   1.14931
         C   9   1.16563
         C   10  1.18294
         ")
dat = read.table(textConnection(Input),header=TRUE)

simplemodel <- map2stan(
  alist(
    Size ~ dnorm( mu , sigma ) , #normally distributed likelihood function
    mu <- a[Group] + b * Time, #varying intercept by variable "Group"
    a[Group] ~ dnorm( a_mu , a_sigma ), #adaptive priors, b/c IDK
    b ~ dnorm(time_mu, time_sigma),
    a_mu ~ dnorm(0,1),
    a_sigma ~ dcauchy(0,2.5),
    time_mu ~ dnorm(0,1),
    time_sigma ~ dcauchy(0,2.5),
    sigma ~ dcauchy(0, 2.5) #prior to sigma
  ),
  data=dat, iter=1000, warmup=100, chains=1, verbose=T, 
  cores=4, control = list(adapt_delta = 0.99, max_treedepth = 15))
```

From there, use the precis function do get your coefficients.

```
> precis(simplemodel, depth = 2)
           mean   sd  5.5% 94.5% n_eff Rhat
a[1]       1.08 0.00  1.07  1.08   712 1.00
a[2]       1.03 0.00  1.02  1.03   964 1.00
a[3]       1.03 0.00  1.02  1.03   846 1.00
b          0.02 0.00  0.01  0.02   886 1.00
a_mu       1.03 0.15  0.88  1.17   399 1.00
a_sigma    0.13 0.22  0.02  0.45    88 1.00
time_mu    0.00 0.67 -1.17  1.11   199 1.00
time_sigma 1.60 1.97  0.13  4.52   165 1.01
sigma      0.00 0.00  0.00  0.01   426 1.00
```